# Runtime exception : ClassCastException android.os.Bundle cannot be cast to Parcelable class

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, android-pendingintent, classcastexception

I get this crash when I installed the new code and ran it, below I have attached the old and the new code. Please let me know how can we fix things like these?

**Old Code:**

```
// data class
public class X {
  int val;
  ....
  ....
}

public final HelperClass {
  static Bundle toBundle(X obj) {
    toDataMap(obj).toBundle();
  }

  static DataMap toDataMap(X obj) {
    DataMap dataMap = new DataMap();
    dataMap.putInt("id", obj.val);
    ....
    ....
    return dataMap;
  }
}

// used in an activity on a onClick
context.startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_VIEW)
                         .putExtra(X_INSTANCE_EXTRA, HelperClass.toBundle(new X())));

// received in the activity started by the intent
X obj = bundle.getBundle(X_INSTANCE_EXTRA);
```

**New Code :**

```
// data class
public class X implements Parcelable {
  int val;
  ....
  ....

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(val);
    ...
    ...
  }

  public static final Parcelable.Creator<X> CREATOR =
      new Parcelable.Creator<X>() {
        @Override
        public X createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
          X obj = new X();
          x.val = in.readInt();
          ...}
      };
}

// used in an activity on a onClick
context.startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_VIEW)
                         .putExtra(X_INSTANCE_EXTRA, new X());

// received in the activity started by the intent
X obj = intent.getParcelableExtra(X_INSTANCE_EXTRA);
```

I get the error at the last line of the new code stating

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.Bundle cannot be cast to X
```

Is it because of some intent fired on old code and received in the new code?

Comment: Looks like it. Did you uninstall and reinstall your app between old and new code?

Comment: But I don't want my users to face this crash, is there a way to handle this backward compatibility?

Comment: So users have a version with the old code and you want to update to the new code?

Comment: Do you always get this crash? What happens if you uninstall the old code and install the new code. Do you still get the crash?

Comment: So suppose the user gets the next update over-the-air, they might get this crash, this does goes away after re-start

Comment: I still don't understand. I don't see a case where the old code and the new code is running at the same time. Is there somewhere else where you do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make changes like this to code that is already in the field (installed on user's devices) then you need to make your changes backwards compatible. One example would be to use a different key for `X_INSTANCE_EXTRA` (ie: change the name) so that there are no conflicts with older code. Another way would be to expect the exception and verify the type of object returned here:

```
X obj = intent.getParcelableExtra(X_INSTANCE_EXTRA);
```

like this:

```
try {
    X obj = intent.getParcelableExtra(X_INSTANCE_EXTRA);
    // Extra is the correct type, continue processing...
} catch (ClassCastException e) {
    // Not of the correct type, so this is old stuff, do something appropriate...
}
```

This is kinda ugly and I wouldn't normally do this. You need to think about backwards compatibility when you make changes to software that is already out in the field. Try to make your changes so that the old stuff doesn't break.